# Publishing to ios store failing with "Sign in with the app-specific password"

Tags: ios, nativescript

I'm trying to publish to the app store with

`tns publish ios APPLE-ID PASSWORD --ipa PATH-TO-IPA-FILE`

I get the following error message

`Unable to connect to iTunes Connect
Sign in with the app-specific password you generated. If you forgot the app-specific password or need to create a new one, go to appleid.apple.com (-22938)`

I went to the site and created a password - just used a random label name.

Now what? Where do I put this password??

Using the latest NS dev tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the app-specific password instead of the account password:

```
tns publish ios APPLE-ID APP-SPECIFIC-PASSWORD --ipa PATH-TO-IPA-FILE
```